# How do I reference a resource from a module in Azure Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I have a fairly simple Bicep script for creating a Cosmos Database as well as a container within it:

```
resource cosmos_db_live 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2022-05-15' = {
    parent: cosmos_account
    name: 'live'
    properties: {
        resource: {
            id: 'live'
        }
        options: {
            throughput: 600
        }
    }
}

resource cosmos_container 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-05-15' = {
    parent: cosmos_db_live
    name: 'container_name'
    properties: {
        resource: {
            id: 'container_name'
            partitionKey: {
                paths: ['/partition']
            }
            conflictResolutionPolicy: {
                mode: 'LastWriterWins'
                conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
            }
            indexingPolicy: {
                indexingMode: 'consistent'
                automatic: true
                includedPaths: [{path: '/*'}]
                excludedPaths: [{path: '/"_etag"/?'}]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works great. However I now want to create multiple containers all with the same structure so I am attempting to template the container definition out to a module:

```
param name string
param partition string

resource cosmos_container 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-05-15' = {
    name: name
    properties: {
        resource: {
            id: name
            partitionKey: {
                paths: ['/${partition}']
            }
            conflictResolutionPolicy: {
                mode: 'LastWriterWins'
                conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
            }
            indexingPolicy: {
                indexingMode: 'consistent'
                automatic: true
                includedPaths: [{path: '/*'}]
                excludedPaths: [{path: '/"_etag"/?'}]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now have no idea how to link it back to the parent. I cant use `parent:`  within the module because I cant find a way to pass the DB resource into the module via the toplevel file. I cant use `parent:`  within the module call because it is not a valid operation. I cant call the module from within the parent resource because it is not valid syntax.

How can I call the above module from my parent file and have dependencies automatically resolved as if it was all in one file? Is this not supported? There should be a very basic way to do this (unless I am missing something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in Bicep. Here's a sample that does name and partition key as well as different throughput values on each container.

More examples in [Bicep Quickstart Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/quickstart-loops?tabs=CLI).

```
param accountName string
param location string
param primaryRegion string
param databaseName string
param containersConfig object

var locations = [
  {
    locationName: primaryRegion
    failoverPriority: 0
    isZoneRedundant: false
  }
]

resource account 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-05-15' = {
  name: toLower(accountName)
  location: location
  kind: 'GlobalDocumentDB'
  properties: {
    consistencyPolicy: { defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Session'}
    locations: locations
    databaseAccountOfferType: 'Standard'
  }
}

resource database 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2022-05-15' = {
  parent: account
  name: databaseName
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: databaseName
    }
  }
}

resource containers 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-05-15' = [for containerConfig in items(containersConfig): {
  parent: database
  name: '${containerConfig.value.name}'
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: '${containerConfig.value.name}'
      partitionKey: {
        paths: [
          '${containerConfig.value.partitionKey}'
        ]
        kind: 'Hash'
      }
      indexingPolicy: {
        indexingMode: 'consistent'
        includedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/*'
          }
        ]
        excludedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/_etag/?'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    options: {
      throughput: containerConfig.value.throughput
    }
  }
}]
```

Then the parameter file.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "accountName": {
      "value": "my-cosmos-account"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "West US"
    },
    "primaryRegion": {
      "value": "West US"
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "value": "myDatabase"
    },
    "containersConfig": {
      "value": {
        "container1": {
          "name": "myContainer1",
          "partitionKey": "/myPartitionKey1",
          "throughput": 400
        },
        "container2": {
          "name": "myContainer2",
          "partitionKey": "/myPartitionKey2",
          "throughput": 500
        },
        "container3": {
          "name": "myContainer3",
          "partitionKey": "/myPartitionKey3",
          "throughput": 600
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I noticed you are using database throughput. I advise against sharing database throughput with containers if they have highly asymmetric request and storage needs. Good when the containers are all roughly equal. for those that are not, give them their own throughput.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of using loops although this solution still requires everything in a single file. I will take a look into spitting the throughput however as they are all relatively equal and the application itself is very light on load I might only switch if it becomes a problem in the future! :)

Comment: Easy enough to use a parameter file. Updated the answer to use that instead of single file.

Comment: Ack on your throughput usage. If you do need to switch keep in mind that you'll need to create a new container, then copy all the data to it. That used to be somewhat painful but is easier now with this feature though it does require some downtime today. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/intra-account-container-copy

Answer (score 2):

Passing resources across modules isn't as simple as it could be today (we're working on it) but you can emulate it by using the `existing` keyword in the module...  So assuming your module contains only the container resource declaration (and the account & db are in the main.bicep file) e.g.

```
param dbAccountName string
param sqlDbName string

param name string
param partition string

resource dbAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-05-15' existing = {
  name: dbAccountName
}
resource sqlDb 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2022-05-15' existing = {
  parent: dbAccount
  name: sqlDbName
}

resource cosmos_container 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-05-15' = {
  parent: sqlDb
  name: name
  properties: {

  }
}
```